# Integrating Google Plus Community into Slack

Tags: google-plus, slack-api

At the coding boot camp I am attending, we use both Slack and a Google Community to communicate online. Seems like people are defaulting to the Google Community when they want to share resources, links to articles, etc. and using Slack just for chat. It would be nice if new posts in the Google Community were displayed within slack.

There doesn't appear to be an RSS feed for Google Communities. And this [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639) probably doesn't bode well. Any other ideas?